# node.js script blocks for some time (on beaglebone)

Tags: node.js, serial-port, socket.io

I have written a controller/communication application with a web based frontend
using **node.js (0.8.15)**. **socket.io** performs periodic data exchange.

My backend needs to talk (via rs232 at 19200bps) to 3 embedded boards every second.
Those boards trigger watchdogs when they see a longer communication failure.

When I start my node.js app everything is fine, communication works.
As soon as there is a connect to my web server **for the first
time** I see that rs232 communication is stopped for about 5-10 seconds.

I do not see this effect when reloading the web page.
Using http or https makes no difference.
Trying to run node with options like **--nolazy** or **--noopt** or **--noalways_full_compiler** does not change anything.

Here are the relevant parts of my web server:

```
var requests =
[ { method: 'GET', pattern: '/',               type: 'text/html', subst: '/index.html' },
  { method: 'GET', pattern: '/index.html',     type: 'text/html' },
  { method: 'GET', pattern: '/favicon.ico',    type: 'image/x-icon' },
  { method: 'GET', pattern: '/js/[^/]+\.js',   type: 'text/javascript' },
  { method: 'GET', pattern: '/css/[^/]+\.css', type: 'text/css' },
  { method: 'GET', pattern: '/img/[^/]+\.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' },
  { method: 'GET', pattern: '/img/[^/]+.png',  type: 'image/png' },
];

function response (req, res)
{
  var method = req.method;
  var path = Path.normalize (Url.parse (req.url).pathname);

  console.log (method+' '+path);
  for (i = -1; ++i < requests.length;)
  {
    var r = requests[i];
    if (r.method == method && path.search ('^'+r.pattern+'$') == 0)
    {
      if ('subst' in r)
      {
        path = r.subst;
      };
      if (r.type.match (/^text/))
      {
        Fs.readFile (__dirname+path, 'utf8', function (err, data)
        {
          if (err)
          {
            res.writeHead (500);
            res.end ('Error reading '+path);
          }
          else
          {
            res.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': r.type});
            res.end (data, 'utf8');
          }
        });
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        Fs.readFile (__dirname+path, function (err, data)
        {
          if (err)
          {
            res.writeHead (500);
            res.end ('Error reading '+path);
          }
          else
          {
            res.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': r.type});
            res.end (data);
          }
        });
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  console.log ('error 404');
  res.writeHead (404);
  res.end ();
}

var httpServer = Http.createServer (response);
httpServer.listen (47080);
console.log ('http server running at port 47080');
var basic = Auth ({
  authRealm : "controller",
  authFile : __dirname + '/users.htpasswd'
});

function httpsResponse (req, res)
{
  basic.apply (req, res, function (username)
  {
    response (req, res);
  });
}

var options = {
  key: Fs.readFileSync (__dirname + '/controller.pem'),
  cert: Fs.readFileSync (__dirname + '/controller.cert')
};
var httpsServer = Https.createServer (options, httpsResponse);

httpsServer.listen(47443);
console.log ('https server running at port 47443');

function connected (socket)
{
  console.log ('Listener connected');
  theApp.addSocket (socket);
  socket.on ('disconnect', function ()
  {
    theApp.removeSocket (socket);
  });
}

var httpListen = Io.listen (httpServer,   { 'log level':1 });
var httpsListen = Io.listen (httpsServer, { 'log level':1 });
httpListen.sockets.on ('connection', connected);
httpsListen.sockets.on ('connection', connected);
```

Comment: There are some issues with this code snippet. First, and arguably least importantly, you're not following node conventions such as Egyptian braces and spacing around functions. Take a look [here](http://nodeguide.com/style.html) for some tips.

Comment: Far more significant is the variable 'i' which does not have a `var`, and so will be globally assigned (or updated). You have an increment in the first `for` loop that should really be in the third position rather than the second. Some of your blocks have trailing semicolons, which should not be there. The socket disconnection events should probably be handled with `once` rather than `on`.

I'm not completely sure what `requests` is. What does this look like?

Comment: I added requests (see above)

Comment: I corrected the for loop variable. As to be expected the problem remains.

Comment: About style: I am no javascript programmer. This is just a hobby project. I come from C / C++. The pre-incremented loop variable is a kind of personal style. In old 8-bit times it improved the performance of my z80 code;-)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my application into two processes: One
for the web server and one for the serial communication.
That improved things but did niot solve the problem.

The real problem seems to be the garbage collector.

After starting node with --expose-gc and explicitly
calling global.gc() periodically, the application
runs smoothly.